# Versioning for Java binaries

Tags: java, bazel

I am looking to automatically attach a version number to a Java binary built by Bazel. With the following code, I can only generate the file `hello-world.jar` when running `bazel build //:hello-world`.

```
java_binary(
    name = "hello-world",
    srcs = glob(["src/main/java/com/bmuschko/**/*.java"]),
    main_class = "com.bmuschko.HelloWorld"
)
```

What I would like to produce is a way to define a version e.g. 1.2.3 which would automatically produce the file `hello-world-1.2.3.jar` similar to other build tools like Maven or Gradle. This functionality doesn't seem to be a built-in feature in Bazel as indicated by [issue-1291](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/1291).

What's the idiomatic way to implement the described use case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current idiomatic approach to rename files in Bazel is through using a simple genrule:

```
VERSION = "1.2.3"

genrule(
    name = "versioned_hello_world",
    srcs = [":hello-world.jar"],
    outs = [":hello-world-%s.jar" % VERSION],
    cmd = "cp $< $@",
)
```

To build, run `$ bazel build :versioned_hello_world` or `$ bazel build :hello-world-1.2.3.jar`.